# Does IntelliJ has a function to visualize the relationship between two specific tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea, foreign-keys

I'm working with a big mySQL database in IntelliJ. 
I'm trying to join two tables which aren't in a direct key-relation to each other. Hence I have to join over multiple tables.
Because I barley know the database scheme, I can't find out these tables in a appropriate time. I know that IntelliJ has a function which can visualize all tables with their relations within the database but does it also provide a function where I can **find out all tables in between two specific tables**?

Comment: I don't know that IntelliJ has this, but in any case you should probably be looking at the table _definitions_ to decide what the relationship are.  Look for primary/foreign key relationships, and the order of joining should be obvious.

Comment: thanks. To look up all definitions in the database doesn't really work for me. I was trying this way for some while but the database is too big..

Comment: A visual by itself I would expect to be fairly useless.  Most likely, the tables you plan to join have primary-foreign key relationships.  The easiest place to handle your problem IMO would be in MySQL Workbench.  Just open the database there and have a look.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm going to do now - thanks!

Comment: It's installed and running. Now i have a huge Diagramm of all my tables with relations. It's horrible compared to IntelliJ's. What would you suggest to do next to finde the tables in between the two tables I want to join? Is there a way so select two tables and see over which tables I have to go to?

Comment: As I keep saying, look for _primary_ and _foreign_ keys.  This likely will tell you the relationships between the tables.  If there are no keys defined on certain tables, then you might have to go by name.  How many tables do you have?  If only a few, why not post the definitions in your question and we can tease it apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can get help from Intellij partially for your task, using the visualization feature as follows-

[image]

The relationship between tables are clearly shown.
For your question, you need to check the primary and foreign keys for each table which are easy to know as they are highlighted.
Traversing them you can find the relationship.